# pegar nome do campo na query e popular outro!

Tags: mysql, sql

estou fazendo uma pesquisa no banco.

Na tabela, tenho 6 datas: `data1, data2, data3, data4, data5 e data6.`

Estou varrendo essas datas para saber qual delas combina com o mês atual.

Isso já está sendo feito:

```
...
WHERE 
 YEAR(data1) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(data1) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) OR
 YEAR(data2) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(data2) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) OR
 YEAR(data3) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(data3) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) OR
 YEAR(data4) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(data4) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) OR
 YEAR(data5) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(data5) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) OR
 YEAR(data6) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(data6) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
ORDER BY cliente, tipo, id
```

Agora preciso descobrir em qual data (1,2,3,4,5 ou 6) que caiu para pegar esse número procurar em outro campo chamado `valorX`, onde **x** é o valor do campo data (1,2,3,4,5 ou 6) e concatenar e retornar quantos reais estão nesse campo.

Alguém me ajuda nessa lógica?

Comment: Já avaliou a utilização do CASE / WHEN?

Comment: Ainda não. Na verdade não sei como fazer!
Minha dificuldade aqui está lógica. Eu acho!

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi sua construção para o valor do ano e mês a serem pesquisados mas experimente colocar na lista de campos de seu SELECT:

```
SUM (CASE WHEN (year(data1) = ano AND month(data1) = dia) THEN valor1 
     CASE WHEN (year(data2) = ano AND month(data2) = dia) THEN valor2 
     CASE WHEN (year(data3) = ano AND month(data3) = dia) THEN valor3 
     CASE WHEN (year(data4) = ano AND month(data4) = dia) THEN valor4 
     CASE WHEN (year(data5) = ano AND month(data5) = dia) THEN valor5 
     CASE WHEN (year(data6) = ano AND month(data6) = dia) THEN valor6) AS valor_total
```

Por "concatenar" entendi que você deseja somar os valores.

Comment: Acho que da forma que eu estou querendo fazer não vai possível com uma só SQL. Mas é o seguinte: Após a sql decidir em qual campo data (data1, dat2...data6) caiu o ano e o mes passados, então ele vai pegar esse valor (1,2,...6) e vai concatenar com a palavra valor ficando valor1, o valor2, etc... e depois disto buscar qual o conteúdo do mesmo retorno que há no campo valor+numero. Acho que terei que mudar a abordagem pois está ficando muito bagunçado! e pode acabar saindo do foco do fórum.